# Skipping target "RunCodeAnalysis" because it has no inputs

Tags: msbuild

I am currently trying to run code analysis via MSBuild and it is skipping it.

The command I am running is

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln" /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml

and the output is saying

Skipping target "RunCodeAnalysis" because it has no inputs.

I cant find anything on the internet about this error, so I am hoping someone else has encountered it and knows the fix.

### The build output is

C:\Users\michael>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln" /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml /bl
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Framework
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe /bl /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=MyXmlReport.xml C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 8/28/2017 4:04:46 PM.
Project "C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Debug|Any CPU".
Project "C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln" (1) is building "C:\Users\michael\source\repo
s\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sqlproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
GenerateSqlTargetFrameworkMoniker:
Skipping target "GenerateSqlTargetFrameworkMoniker" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input f
iles.
CoreCompile:
Skipping target "CoreCompile" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
SqlBuild:
Skipping target "SqlBuild" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the input files.
CopyFilesToOutputDirectory:
  AdventureWorks -> C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks\bin\Debug\AdventureWorks.dll
GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute:
Skipping target "GenerateTargetFrameworkMonikerAttribute" because all output files are up-to-date with respect to the i
nput files.
RunCodeAnalysis:
Skipping target "RunCodeAnalysis" because it has no inputs.
SqlPrepareForRun:
  AdventureWorks -> C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks\bin\Debug\AdventureWorks.dacpac
Done Building Project "C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sqlproj" (default tar
gets).

Done Building Project "C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln" (default targets).

Deferred Messages

Detailed Build Summary
  ======================

============================== Build Hierarchy (IDs represent configurations) =======================================
  ==============
  Id                  : Exclusive Time   Total Time   Path (Targets)

---

---

0                   : 0.037s           0.386s       C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks.sln (
  )
  . 1                 : 0.349s           0.349s       C:\Users\michael\source\repos\AdventureWorks\AdventureWorks\Adven
  tureWorks.sqlproj ()

============================== Node Utilization (IDs represent configurations) ======================================
  ==============
  Timestamp:            1        Duration   Cumulative

---

---

636395582862251838:   0        0.035s     0.035s
  636395582862605149:   1        0.349s     0.384s ######
  636395582866094463:   0        0.002s     0.386s

---

---

Utilization:          100.0    Average Utilization: 100.0

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

### Time Elapsed 00:00:00.48

Thanks in advance,
Michael

Comment: It says right in your command line text `RunCodeAnalysis=false`. Why is that not true?

Comment: I copied the wrong command. I corrected it in the post. Thank you!

Comment: can you attach a diagnostic build log? `/bl` gives a good self-contained file ideal for looking into such issues